# joda-time and Hibernate - Date gets not stored in UTC

Tags: java, hibernate, jodatime

I'm using `DateTime` in order to store timestamps on my server in UTC-Time:

```
// @Entity ..
@NotNull
@Column(name="DATE")
@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")
private DateTime date;
```

During the server boot up I'm doing this:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

to make sure that `new DateTime()` will always be in UTC-Time and this is how I prepare a date to get stored:

```
DateTime utc = new DateTime();
utc = utc.dayOfMonth().roundFloorCopy();

DateTime thisMonday = utc.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
DateTime thisTuesday = thisMonday.plusDays(1);
```

If I'm debugging this I see e.g.

> `2015-08-31 00:00:00` and `2015-09-01 00:00:00`

but as I look into the database I see that

> `2015-08-31 02:00:00` and `2015-09-01 02:00:00`

got stored there. It's +2h which is my local UTC offset (Berlin/Vienna).

Why is this happening and how can I make sure that my server stores all times in UTC?

Answer (score 1):

You are using Jadira for converting JodaTime types to SQL date/time types. Use these JPA/Hibernate properties to tell Jadira what time zone should be applied when sending data to the DB

```
<properties>
    <property name="jadira.usertype.javaZone" value="UTC" /> <!-- or "jvm" to use your default JVM TZ, explicit Europe/Berlin or +02:00 etc. -->
    <property name="jadira.usertype.databaseZone" value="UTC" /> <!-- or "jvm" to use your default JVM TZ or +02:00 etc. But you'd better not use an explicit TZ with a DST change -->
</properties>
```

See [Jadira User Guide](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/usertype-userguide.html) for details.

Other thing is that maybe your DB is using your connection information to display you the timestamps in your time zone? That depends on which DB it is and which tool you use to connect. SQL Developer (for Oracle DB) is aware of your computer's TZ and sets the connection TZ to that.